# req.files is always null express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, multer, express-jwt

TLDR : express-jwt creates conflicts with packages adding stuff in the req parameter of the node.js API (express-upload, multer for example).

I'm working on a node.js API and I can't remove any package. I'm trying to upload files from the front end to the API. I used many packages for that (express-fileupload, multer ...) but none of them fixed my problem. The person who created the API used express-jwt for authentification. It works by adding some information in the req.user field on the API.

My problem is that the packages used to upload files in nodejs seems to create conflicts with express-jwt. If i disable it, req.files is populated as it should and everything works perfectly. But when i reinstall express-jwt, req.files is always null. I can't just use another authentification package. I have no idea to solve this problem.

Comment: You could introduce a custom middleware function that runs right after `express-fileupload` and before `express-jwt` then store the contents of `req.files` inside of `res.locals.files` and then use that instead. That's one of the options.

Comment: @goto1 ok so after commenting this line : `app.use(expressJwt({secret: PUBLIC, strict : false}).unless({path : unless}));` ,  req.files is not null anymore. I don't understand because the line of code that causes the problem is in the first middleware, and express-fileupload appears just before the route i'm woking on ... Any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure how these packages work behind the scenes so I am not sure what's happening. I'd suggest logging `req.files` before and after the `expressJwt` middleware and see if there's any difference.

Comment: @goto1 You were right, it works now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Happen when multiple files but works if send singles files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to call the express-fileupload middleware first. I added the following code and req.files was accessible in any middleware called after that.

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    console.log("user :  " + req.user + " ===== files : " + req.files);
    next();
})
```

For any reason if you call express-jwt first, req.files will not be populated. For me the line that caused the conflict was this one :

```
app.use(expressJwt({secret: PUBLIC, strict : false}).unless({path : unless}));
```